# Fails to set bgcolor on StaticText on Raspberry pi (but not in Win10)

Tags: python, wxpython, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to set the backgroundcolor of a StaticText in wxPython. I am using the method 
`.SetBackgroundColour('Red')`. That works as expected when I run my code on windows 10. However, when it runs on a Raspberry pi it fails to set the background colour (and the text alignment). Can someone help?

[Picture: Result on windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fGx4.png)

[Picture: Result on Raspberry pi 3b+](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxC0O.png)

*The code and a wheel file built on the raspberry for wxPython4.0.3 can be found on my Github:* https://github.com/danneedebro/Problem_bgcolor_static_text

This is my simplified code:

`Main.py`

```
import wx


class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title='Window', size=(300, 100))

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        LblTextWithBgColor = wx.StaticText(panel, label='This text should have a red background', size=(250, 20), style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        LblTextWithBgColor.SetForegroundColour('Green')
        LblTextWithBgColor.SetBackgroundColour('Red')
        self.Show()


app = wx.App()
Example(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set the background color of `wx.StaticText` in GTK. The label is just drawn on the parent window, which prevents you from doing much of anything with the widget. This is documented in a non-obvious location:

- https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.stattext.html

However you can use the `wx.lib.stattext` instead as it is a generic widget that should work the same way on all platforms.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I will try this. I implemented a fix that added a extra panel in my real application but I didn't manage to fix the text alignment so this is definitly better.