# Can't set (some types of) border on wx.Panel on Raspbian

Tags: python, wxpython

I have problem setting a border on some text labels on my Raspberry Pi. Works fine in Windows but fails on raspbian. Not all borders fail. I have no trouble with wx.BORDER_RAISED or wx.BORDER_SUNKEN but the others.

Is this a platform issue or is there some trick/setting involved that I am missing (ie specify some border thickness or something).

Here's my sample code

```
import wx

class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(900, 750))
        self.SetBackgroundColour('Black')
        self.SetForegroundColour("White")

        PanelMain = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        PanelMain.SetForegroundColour("White")
        PanelMain.SetBackgroundColour("Black")
        SizerMain = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        for i in range(3):
            PanelSub = wx.Panel(PanelMain, -1, style=wx.BORDER_STATIC)
            PanelSub.SetBackgroundColour("Black")
            lblNew = wx.StaticText(PanelSub, -1, label="Hello {}".format(i))
            lblNew.SetForegroundColour("White")
            lblNew.SetBackgroundColour("Green" if i == 0 else "Blue")
            SizerMain.Add(PanelSub, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        PanelMain.SetSizer(SizerMain)
        SizerMain.Fit(PanelMain)

        self.Show()


app = wx.App()
Example(None, title='Boxes')
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a solution to this one so this is what I did.

First I created a custom wx.Panel-class like this

```
class MyCustomPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, Parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, Parent, -1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnSize)

    def OnSize(self, event):
        self.Refresh()
        event.Skip()

    def OnPaint(self, event):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen("Gray", width=1))
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush("black", wx.TRANSPARENT)) 
        mySize = self.GetSize()
        dc.DrawRectangle(0,0, mySize.GetWidth(), mySize.GetHeight())
```

This class can be used as a normal panel but has a box around itself. This is the main program:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.stattext as ST

class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(900, 750))
        self.SetBackgroundColour('Black')
        self.SetForegroundColour("White")

        PanelMain = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        PanelMain.SetForegroundColour("White")
        PanelMain.SetBackgroundColour("Black")
        SizerMain = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        for i in range(3):
            PanelSub = MyCustomPanel(PanelMain)
            PanelSub.SetBackgroundColour("Black")
            lblNew = ST.GenStaticText(PanelSub, -1, label="Hello {}".format(i))
            lblNew.SetForegroundColour("White")
            lblNew.SetBackgroundColour("Green" if i == 0 else "Blue")
            SizerMain.Add(PanelSub, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5)

        PanelMain.SetSizer(SizerMain)
        SizerMain.Fit(PanelMain)

        self.Show()


app = wx.App()
Example(None, title='Boxes')
app.MainLoop()
```

**Note:** Replaced **`wx.StaticText`** with **`ST.GenStaticText`** [as this works better on GTK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53630830/fails-to-set-bgcolor-on-statictext-on-raspberry-pi-but-not-in-win10)

**Note 2:** Unfortunately the border is overlapped by the textbox in this simple example (see this picture below ). This isn't the case in my real code as i use a inner sizer there. In the simple example, this can be avoided by adding a inner sizer that contains the text-labels.

[image: Textbox overlaps the border of the panel]